# Can I run Ubuntu installed on a USB flashdrive from the flashdrive to safely use the internet on an NT desktop

Tags: usb, internet, security

I have an NT desktop I want to continue to use but do not want to be exposed to security issues after April 8.  I've read I can boot the computer from a flashdrive with a Linux based OS installed on it and use the internet off the flashdrive while keeping the desktop safe.  Will Ubuntu work for this?  If so how big of a flashdrive will I need?  Thanks.

In response to Danatela, yes I want to place a persistence file onto that USB.

Comment: Do you want to place _persistence_ file onto that USB? Persistence file helps you keep settings but requires more space.

Comment: If an old NT machine, you may not have much RAM nor good video. Full Ubuntu needs a better system. But Lubuntu may work with an older system. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can be created in even 1GB USB-flash stick.
There are many software available to make your live Ubuntu.
one is here.and its free

```
Linux live USB creator.
You can get it by its official site 
linuxliveusb.com/download
```